# A particular presheaf on a small category. What if it's representable?

Tags: category-theory, functors, yoneda-lemma, presheaves

We consider a small category $\mathcal{C}$ with binary products, and we consider, for any objects $A, B$ of $\mathcal{C}$, the assignments

\begin{eqnarray*}
F :\,\, &\mathcal{C}^\text{op} &\longrightarrow \textbf{Set} \\
&X &\mapsto \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X \times A, B) \\
&X'\xrightarrow{\bar{f}} X &\mapsto - \circ f\times \text{id}_A.
\end{eqnarray*}

After some fidgeting with compositions and reversals of the order of morphisms in opposite categories, I managed to prove this is a functor, and therefore, in fact, a presheaf (on $\mathcal{C}$). Now I am asked the following somewhat vague question: 'what does it say about $\mathcal{C}$ if this functor is representable?

In the preceding exercises, I have shown that $\mathcal{C}$ has binary products iff (for $y$ the Yoneda embedding) $y(A) \times y(B)$ is representable, and also that $\mathcal{C}$ has a terminal object iff a (c.q. *'the'*) terminal object of $[\mathcal{C}^\text{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ is representable. However I'm not sure how any it this (certainly the latter) ties into this, nor what the question is getting at. Can someone point me in a likely sensible direction?

Cheers.

Comment: Hint: this functor is always representable when $\mathcal C$ is Set. (Take FinSet if you like, for size reasons.) What is its representing object?

Comment: I'm not sure about the hint, but what I have now shown is that, if $D$ is the representing object, there is, for every object $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$, a bijective correspondence between maps $C \times A \to B$ and maps $C \to D$. This is beginning to smell like a statement about exponentials...

Comment: The logic remains reversed, though. *Assuming* that $\mathcal{C}$ is ccc, for example, or at least, that $B$ is an exponentiable object, then the bijectivity of the mapping Hom$_\mathcal{C}(C \times A, B) \to \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(C, B^A)$ would then also give a bijection (probably natural) $\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(C, B^A) \tilde\to \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(C, D)$, with will probably give us $y(D) \cong y(B^A)$, and hence $D \cong B^A$. I'm still not sure what that says about $\mathcal{C}$ as a whole, though..

Comment: That's the whole point. This presheaf is representable if and only if $B^A$ exists, and the representing object is $B^A$.

Comment: Do we even need the ‘only if’ here? And again: what does that say about $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: If you have it for all $A$ and $B$ then the category is cartesian closed. And conversely, of course. I think you are overcomplicating things and confusing yourself.

Comment: This is likely, I tend to do that a lot ;) Thanks!

Comment: Ah, perhaps I fell over this question too much: *had we only had* the bijection Hom$(C \times A, B) \cong \text{Hom}(C, D)$, would that automatically prove existence of $B^A$?
Another question: why can it not occur that there is *no* arrow $B^A × A \to B$ al all? Then the exponential $B^A$ cannot exist and the whole argument breaks down. Apparently, an arrow $B^A × A \to B$ will always exists (in our context). Why? Can we point to it?

Answer (score 1):

Solution attempt:

Suppose $F$ is representable: $(\exists D \in \mathcal{C}_0)(F \cong y(D))$. Then we get, for any object $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$:

$$y(D)(C) = \text{Hom}(C, D) \leftrightarrow \text{Hom}(C \times A, B) = F(C).
$$

If we furthermore assume that $B^A$ exists (with some map ev$_A : B^A \times A \to B)$, then we also have a bijection
$$\text{Hom}(C \times A, B) \leftrightarrow \text{Hom}(C, B^A).
$$
Combining this, this yields
$$y(D)(C) \leftrightarrow \text{Hom}(C, B^A) = y(B^A)(C),
$$ whence ($y$ being fully faithful and injective on objects) $D \cong B^A$.

Thus: *if* $(B^A, \text{ev}_A)$ exists, then $B^A \cong D$.

However, there is (in my mind) no reason to assume *that* $(B^A, \text{ev}_A)$ exists...

That aside: even if I were to prove that it does, i.e., that $B$ is exponentiable and $B^A \cong D$, what does that say about $\mathcal{C}$ as a whole? Is it that, as $A, B$ were arbitraty, $\mathcal{C}$ is ccc?